# Let $A=(a_{ij})_{2\times 2}$ matrix such that square sum of each row and column is less the or equal to 1. Then is operator norm of $A\leq1$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Here we assume that square sum of each row and column is less the or equal to 1, i.e. $|a_{11}|^2+|a_{12}|^2\leq 1;|a_{11}|^2+|a_{21}|^2\leq 1; |a_{21}|^2+|a_{22}|^2\leq 1; |a_{12}|^2+|a_{22}|^2\leq 1$. Then I able to show that $\|A\|_{op}\leq 4$. But I am not able to check whether $\|A\|_{op}\leq 1$ or not.

Comment: No: let $A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$: $A$ satisfies your condition but has $\sqrt{2}$ as an eigenvalue so its operator norm is at least $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Operator norm from which norm to which norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment above the norm is bounded by $\sqrt{2}$.
It is just Cauchy-Schwartz inequality applied twice, i.e. 
$$||Ax||=\sqrt{(a_{11}x_1 + a_{12}x_2)^2 + (a_{21}x_1 +a_{22}x_2)^2}<=
\sqrt{(a_{11}^2 +a_{12}^2)(x_1^2 +x_2^2) +(a_{21}^2 +a_{22}^2)(x_1^2 +x_2^2)}<=
\sqrt{2(x_1^2 + x_2^2)} <= \sqrt{2}||x||$$
Also, all is needed is the assumption on rows length not to be bigger than 1.